# Why cannot I unstack this pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas that looks like this:

```
n_y                                                       0         1         2         3         4   ...        53        54        55        56        57
variable                     n_channel n_pulse n_x                                                    ...                                                  
Total collected charge (V s) 1         1       0    0.000021  0.000039  0.000028  0.000029  0.000030  ...  0.000099  0.000085  0.000031  0.000017  0.000035
                                               1    0.000028  0.000133  0.000046  0.000049  0.000063  ...  0.000237  0.000165  0.000037  0.000036  0.000067
                                               2    0.000022  0.000027  0.000054  0.000075  0.000023  ...  0.000105  0.000045  0.000122  0.000044  0.000022
                                               3    0.000042  0.000171  0.000016  0.000027  0.000046  ...  0.000030  0.000054  0.000055  0.000103  0.000044
                                               4    0.000031  0.000020  0.000043  0.000017  0.000028  ...  0.000024  0.000033  0.000040  0.000069  0.000034
...                                                      ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
                             4         2       53   0.000491  0.000047  0.000014  0.000025  0.000027  ...  0.000048  0.000029  0.000089  0.000051  0.000026
                                               54   0.000022  0.000081  0.000069  0.000050  0.000038  ...  0.000040  0.000077  0.000039  0.000033  0.000017
                                               55   0.000081  0.000091  0.000015  0.000072  0.000016  ...  0.000042  0.000046  0.000024  0.000087  0.000026
                                               56   0.000031  0.000049  0.000273  0.000022  0.000122  ...  0.000028  0.000020  0.000033  0.000053  0.000022
                                               57   0.000027  0.000018  0.000069  0.000012  0.000048  ...  0.000117  0.000031  0.000084  0.000019  0.000018

[2320 rows x 58 columns]
```

I want to [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the `variable` level. I keep getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

I made a MWE to experiment with this:

```py
import pandas
import numpy

df = []
stuff = []
for variable in ['amplitude','time']:
    for n_channel in ['CH1','CH2','CH3']:
        for n_x in range(9):
            for n_y in range(9):
                for n_pulse in [1,2]:
                    stuff.append(
                        dict(
                            variable = variable,
                            n_channel = n_channel,
                            n_x = n_x,
                            n_y = n_y,
                            whatever = numpy.random.rand(),
                            n_pulse = n_pulse,
                        )
                    )
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(stuff)
df = pandas.pivot_table(
    data = df,
    values = df.columns,
    index = ['variable','n_channel','n_pulse','n_x'],
    columns = 'n_y',
)
df = df['whatever']
print(df)
df = df.unstack('variable')
print(df)
```

This is working fine... The first `print` shows:

```
n_y                                     0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
variable  n_channel n_pulse n_x                                                                                          
amplitude CH1       1       0    0.318155  0.318907  0.819447  0.743255  0.478731  0.186771  0.801281  0.032142  0.183628
                            1    0.418701  0.404246  0.866815  0.907896  0.469923  0.395304  0.267957  0.259414  0.657171
                            2    0.344421  0.512340  0.227376  0.017938  0.947097  0.421796  0.024147  0.109382  0.998842
                            3    0.917094  0.454799  0.421441  0.846659  0.657387  0.914102  0.347941  0.784530  0.263389
                            4    0.746022  0.074256  0.275227  0.312784  0.945559  0.727171  0.097169  0.669294  0.124092
...                                   ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
time      CH3       2       4    0.413624  0.622738  0.062325  0.796511  0.765223  0.568922  0.521804  0.059481  0.698582
                            5    0.490076  0.053765  0.094804  0.122796  0.249527  0.915555  0.238314  0.282287  0.193821
                            6    0.728340  0.423650  0.295858  0.867221  0.987413  0.515603  0.615101  0.534728  0.302426
                            7    0.086354  0.697638  0.708708  0.464658  0.972898  0.592239  0.144225  0.029943  0.715472
                            8    0.983830  0.881102  0.855573  0.719386  0.795557  0.550499  0.457187  0.887028  0.077428

[108 rows x 9 columns]
```

which is similar to my original data frame. After the `unstack` the second `print` shows exactly what I want to obtain:

```
n_y                           0                   1                   2            ...         6                   7                   8          
variable              amplitude      time amplitude      time amplitude      time  ... amplitude      time amplitude      time amplitude      time
n_channel n_pulse n_x                                                              ...                                                            
CH1       1       0    0.318155  0.377314  0.318907  0.124907  0.819447  0.033648  ...  0.801281  0.392816  0.032142  0.939812  0.183628  0.217295
                  1    0.418701  0.400172  0.404246  0.605267  0.866815  0.565185  ...  0.267957  0.918827  0.259414  0.925223  0.657171  0.293790
                  2    0.344421  0.544194  0.512340  0.159295  0.227376  0.748645  ...  0.024147  0.838900  0.109382  0.307935  0.998842  0.485162
                  3    0.917094  0.404233  0.454799  0.034856  0.421441  0.035746  ...  0.347941  0.044803  0.784530  0.948064  0.263389  0.413340
                  4    0.746022  0.451766  0.074256  0.401677  0.275227  0.427818  ...  0.097169  0.059010  0.669294  0.652602  0.124092  0.243418
                  5    0.655631  0.270657  0.369451  0.390933  0.433271  0.487986  ...  0.731998  0.152845  0.876073  0.326358  0.874010  0.973927
                  6    0.463634  0.727821  0.343269  0.387025  0.506886  0.742100  ...  0.402282  0.910941  0.629960  0.949041  0.258735  0.434187
                  7    0.273954  0.703639  0.339981  0.851011  0.598395  0.798185  ...  0.091755  0.269656  0.670143  0.573609  0.148111  0.147772
                  8    0.240539  0.557321  0.492881  0.078565  0.725186  0.865216  ...  0.911875  0.492582  0.689864  0.359497  0.535362  0.746846
          2       0    0.422961  0.890133  0.535018  0.570279  0.571138  0.117695  ...  0.013214  0.968708  0.113321  0.224477  0.482554  0.405526
                  1    0.406993  0.026123  0.586861  0.125451  0.503849  0.976586  ...  0.033597  0.374277  0.688245  0.851391  0.726780  0.602009
                  2    0.754604  0.530039  0.092153  0.900987  0.570285  0.403137  ...  0.918097  0.756362  0.796046  0.258649  0.884949  0.881545
                  3    0.339633  0.517753  0.573029  0.157219  0.484687  0.347766  ...  0.110299  0.054327  0.951850  0.852574  0.196102  0.296092
                  4    0.872963  0.805149  0.181597  0.823101  0.025292  0.972622  ...  0.970624  0.002843  0.416082  0.133990  0.191165  0.023063
                  5    0.154898  0.739725  0.711921  0.257430  0.764489  0.542806  ...  0.076698  0.369945  0.687063  0.349555  0.794402  0.919290
                  6    0.773608  0.040250  0.180908  0.901588  0.638054  0.586157  ...  0.374235  0.160535  0.050930  0.745586  0.665319  0.783004
                  7    0.312764  0.702861  0.730731  0.052538  0.929150  0.958350  ...  0.498125  0.473075  0.904690  0.319732  0.104275  0.444401
                  8    0.041232  0.758952  0.735192  0.707305  0.612927  0.594899  ...  0.662133  0.736112  0.233739  0.849167  0.383954  0.244846
CH2       1       0    0.482685  0.030756  0.519471  0.099447  0.933879  0.269588  ...  0.222724  0.654689  0.676711  0.126967  0.267594  0.668274
                  1    0.549225  0.136437  0.178816  0.415080  0.416678  0.938479  ...  0.075785  0.506679  0.233368  0.959007  0.508629  0.916322
                  2    0.821333  0.705575  0.955700  0.151392  0.981931  0.177010  ...  0.250213  0.683854  0.904913  0.469773  0.133955  0.200588
                  3    0.338652  0.784300  0.735776  0.112112  0.527321  0.910160  ...  0.980183  0.282530  0.820129  0.950365  0.350072  0.941842
                  4    0.238885  0.866622  0.045756  0.409689  0.313099  0.774542  ...  0.802145  0.205618  0.609130  0.506542  0.943803  0.333078
                  5    0.108278  0.307909  0.352380  0.552131  0.307273  0.860126  ...  0.899399  0.778098  0.188246  0.729077  0.255168  0.279451
                  6    0.563208  0.115809  0.268294  0.882927  0.805017  0.664985  ...  0.543552  0.033564  0.916331  0.024751  0.208346  0.538154
                  7    0.165855  0.222313  0.213769  0.049349  0.209802  0.280979  ...  0.322356  0.401004  0.795929  0.919803  0.034130  0.088066
                  8    0.276778  0.514858  0.624288  0.716783  0.548286  0.145780  ...  0.097798  0.215031  0.713206  0.684878  0.572296  0.824280
          2       0    0.821332  0.416202  0.212072  0.563054  0.844786  0.159210  ...  0.040958  0.142498  0.421627  0.078418  0.564603  0.800773
                  1    0.289747  0.963189  0.300213  0.289673  0.316227  0.794320  ...  0.958809  0.686297  0.095978  0.718890  0.404255  0.252729
                  2    0.195009  0.786497  0.284339  0.749703  0.324050  0.473740  ...  0.781819  0.461013  0.471294  0.053969  0.793857  0.339071
                  3    0.046489  0.090669  0.249579  0.771584  0.384625  0.159415  ...  0.557342  0.551205  0.566048  0.683298  0.182498  0.316421
                  4    0.525071  0.288015  0.126839  0.370341  0.692128  0.811195  ...  0.609041  0.509900  0.231344  0.679108  0.446438  0.983607
                  5    0.370951  0.651078  0.971907  0.343395  0.077181  0.395344  ...  0.696176  0.443765  0.506720  0.430668  0.425226  0.028401
                  6    0.103904  0.690262  0.013092  0.037656  0.478629  0.916823  ...  0.189386  0.971075  0.412990  0.011442  0.304753  0.806395
                  7    0.845763  0.723639  0.159862  0.514803  0.801334  0.548439  ...  0.610754  0.158426  0.282561  0.923168  0.085974  0.825729
                  8    0.602364  0.432593  0.570190  0.710235  0.594921  0.696220  ...  0.429891  0.068486  0.163413  0.225036  0.588790  0.393577
CH3       1       0    0.412815  0.397042  0.397197  0.233471  0.528925  0.976148  ...  0.704259  0.415330  0.180131  0.177507  0.938230  0.940145
                  1    0.203541  0.748581  0.779031  0.625414  0.720814  0.650374  ...  0.804879  0.211173  0.506444  0.536308  0.850145  0.203682
                  2    0.926183  0.549252  0.896651  0.500793  0.707658  0.740912  ...  0.293263  0.936843  0.556843  0.715463  0.472713  0.556433
                  3    0.571880  0.497707  0.487964  0.376266  0.956032  0.866367  ...  0.154190  0.394322  0.459835  0.102747  0.024374  0.759243
                  4    0.562065  0.086946  0.168839  0.178067  0.442287  0.515272  ...  0.780203  0.444624  0.542385  0.552299  0.639184  0.957356
                  5    0.288680  0.249769  0.255169  0.284534  0.544069  0.387061  ...  0.698532  0.862734  0.014134  0.850374  0.390506  0.102715
                  6    0.689871  0.358891  0.068330  0.039077  0.143581  0.658653  ...  0.953135  0.936750  0.953091  0.412520  0.000104  0.933817
                  7    0.446401  0.808949  0.331366  0.686982  0.647053  0.628440  ...  0.194656  0.130346  0.505650  0.056071  0.212809  0.498561
                  8    0.795113  0.452661  0.017817  0.151491  0.022560  0.451925  ...  0.417213  0.130917  0.507176  0.335206  0.724511  0.555618
          2       0    0.728242  0.107426  0.627625  0.539927  0.340066  0.683591  ...  0.612183  0.266807  0.517194  0.471301  0.762811  0.719649
                  1    0.873102  0.652135  0.434765  0.631983  0.718914  0.509882  ...  0.849363  0.224798  0.305151  0.866502  0.382814  0.897405
                  2    0.947749  0.246105  0.993545  0.441134  0.565680  0.558149  ...  0.159999  0.667146  0.996090  0.836450  0.572647  0.077749
                  3    0.147513  0.717012  0.380867  0.305426  0.205768  0.524098  ...  0.506258  0.413851  0.200404  0.809909  0.908687  0.164276
                  4    0.949666  0.413624  0.339738  0.622738  0.920995  0.062325  ...  0.459207  0.521804  0.073823  0.059481  0.863865  0.698582
                  5    0.262064  0.490076  0.295991  0.053765  0.225085  0.094804  ...  0.994002  0.238314  0.045644  0.282287  0.289603  0.193821
                  6    0.541708  0.728340  0.236228  0.423650  0.225386  0.295858  ...  0.514739  0.615101  0.170154  0.534728  0.309843  0.302426
                  7    0.782316  0.086354  0.342009  0.697638  0.406948  0.708708  ...  0.402539  0.144225  0.760996  0.029943  0.999892  0.715472
                  8    0.384309  0.983830  0.436840  0.881102  0.843084  0.855573  ...  0.447355  0.457187  0.978081  0.887028  0.980453  0.077428

[54 rows x 18 columns]
```

Why could this be failing with my original data frame?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

Probably the same index exists in your dataset. see example below

```
data = [['a', 1, 3, 2], ['a', 1, 2, 1], ['b', 3, 1, 3], ['c', 4, 1, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['i1', 'i2', 'c1', 'c2'])
```

`df`

```
    i1  i2  c1  c2
0   a   1   3   2
1   a   1   2   1
2   b   3   1   3
3   c   4   1   3
```

If set i1 and i2 to index in df, duplicated index exists.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
```

`df1`

```
        c1  c2
i1  i2      
a   1   3   2    <-- duplicated index
    1   2   1    <-- duplicated index
b   3   1   3
c   4   1   3
```

df1(have duplicated index) cannot be unstacked

```
df1.unstack()
```

***ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape***

When doing set_index in df, let's use `append=True` to avoid creating duplicated indexes.

```
df2 = df.set_index(['i1', 'i2'], append=True)
```

`df2`

```
            c1  c2
    i1  i2      
0   a   1   3   2
1   a   1   2   1
2   b   3   1   3
3   c   4   1   3
```

then just unstack df2 and droplevel the index to avoid diplicated index.

```
df2.unstack(level=1).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
    c1          c2
i1  a   b   c   a   b   c
i2                      
1   3.0 NaN NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
1   2.0 NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
3   NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 3.0 NaN
4   NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 3.0
```

The code above is just an example, there will be various ways to make a duplicated index to unique thing.